# How to configure Siema plugin on angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, siema

I'm trying to implement Siema (https://pawelgrzybek.com/siema/)
But it's never working. It's like it never takes the config and doesn't initialize anything.
This is angularjs 1.6.
thx.

**suggestion.component.js**

```
 (function () {
        'use strict';

        angular
            .module('amSuggestions')
            .component('suggestionsSlider', {
                bindings: {
                    suggestions: '<'
                },
                templateUrl: 'suggestions-slider/suggestions-slider.html',
                controller: SuggestionsSliderController
            });

        function SuggestionsSliderController() {

            this.$onInit = function () {
                var mySiema = new Siema({
                    selector: '.siema',
                    perPage: {
                        768: 2,
                        992: 4
                    }
                });
            };
        }
    })();
```

suggestion.jade

```
.siema
    div(ng-repeat="suggestion in $ctrl.suggestions | limitTo: 4")
        suggestion(suggestion="suggestion")
```